# Internal Compiler Error on Array Value-Initialization in VC++14 (VS2015)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, array-initialization, internal-compiler-error

I'm getting an ICE on Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6. Unfortunately, this is happening in a large project, and I can't post the whole code here, and I have been unable to reproduce the problem on a minimal sample. What I'm hoping to get is help in constructing such a sample (to submit to Microsoft) or possibly illumination regarding what's happening and/or what I'm doing wrong.

This is a mock-up of what I'm doing. (Note that the code I'm presenting here **does NOT** generate an ICE; I'm merely using this simple example to explain the situation.)

I have a class `A` which is not copyable (it has a couple of "reference" members) and doesn't have a default constructor. Another class, `B` holds an array of `A`s (plain C array of `A` values, no references/pointers) and I'm initializing this array in the constructor of `B` using uniform initialization syntax. See the sample code below.

```
struct B;

struct A
{
    int & x;
    B * b;

    A (B * b_, int & x_) : x (x_), b (b_) {}
    A (A const &) = delete;
    A & operator = (A const &) = delete;
};

struct B
{
    A a [3];
    int foo;

    B ()
        : a {{this,foo},{this,foo},{nullptr,foo}}  // <-- THE CULPRIT!
        , foo (2)
    {  // <-- This is where the compiler says the error occurs
    }
};

int main ()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

I can't use `std::array` because I need to construct the elements in their final place (can't copy.) I can't use `std::vector` because I need `B` to contain the `A`s.

*Note that* if I don't use an array and use individual variables (e.g. `A a0, a1, a2;`, which I *can* do because the array is small and fixed in size) the ICE goes away. But this is not what I want since I'll lose ability to get to them by index, which I need. I can use a union of the loose variables over the array to solve my ICE problem *and* get indexing (construct using the variables, access using the array,) but I think that would result in "undefined behavior" and seems convoluted.

The obvious differences between the above sample and my actual code (aside from the scale) is that `A` and `B` are classes instead of structs, each is declared/defined in its own source/header file pair, and none of the constructors is inline. (I duplicated these and still couldn't reproduce the ICE.)

For my actual project, I've tried cleaning the built files and rebuild, to no avail. Any suggestions, etc.?

P.S. I'm not sure if my title is suitable. Any suggestions on that?!?!

**UPDATE 1**: This is the compiler file referenced in the C1001 fatal error message: `(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 230)`.

**UPDATE 2**: Since I had forgotten to mention, the codebase compiles cleanly (and correctly) under GCC 4.9.2 in C++14 mode.

Also, I'm compiling with all optimizations disabled.

**UPDATE 3**: I have found out that if I rearrange the member data in `B` and put the array at the very end, the code compiles. I've tried several other permutations and it sometimes does compile and sometimes doesn't. I can't see any patterns regarding what other members coming before the array make the compiler go full ICE! (being UDTs or primitives, having constructors or not, POD or not, reference or pointer or value type, ...)

This means that I have sort of a solution for my problem, although my internal class layout is important to me and this application, I can tolerate the performance hit (due to cache misses resulting from putting some hot data apart from the rest) in order to get past this thing.

However, I still really like a minimal repro of the ICE to be able to submit to Microsoft. I don't want to be stuck with this for the next two years (at least!)

**UPDATE 4**: I have tried VS2015 RC and the ICE is still there (although the error message refers to a different internal line of code, line 247 in the same "main.c" file.)

And I have opened a [bug report on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1368496/c-internal-compiler-error-on-using-braced-initialization-list-for-a-class-member-c-array).

Comment: A has B and B has A, are you sure need such a messy organization?

Comment: An ICE does not necessarily mean that the code cannot be compiled due to a bug in the compiler. It sometimes mean that you're using some combination of features that are currently not handled gracefully by the compiler. Try to follow the recommendations provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y19zxzb2.aspx).

Comment: Take your original source code that ICEs.  Makr a source control shelf.  Now, delete a bunch of stuff you think is irrelevant.  Compile.  ICE?  Shelf, repeat.  No ICE?  Shelf, back up, remove different stuff.  Repeat.  If you pick irrelivant enough stuff, you can get your example really small really quick this way.  Remember your goal is to compile, *not* link: linker errors are a-ok!

Comment: @StraightLine: Each `B` contains some `A`s, and each `A` has a pointer to the `B` that contains it. I see no "messiness". And this is not the cause anyways.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Thanks, I will fiddle with the optimization options and get back to you. I'm not expecting anything though, since it ICEs in Debug too. On an off-topic note, the page you linked to references a KB article that *only applies to VC6 and earlier!* VC6 is what, 17 years old now?! It was talking about an "MS-DOS session" which was a dead giveaway!

Comment: @Yakk: Will do that. It's a bit hard to do for a 50000 LOC codebase that ICEs on line 50001 though. But I will get to the bottom of this...

Comment: Did you try to compile the same code with another C++14 compiler (recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or recent [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) .... ?). If your code compiles ok with another compiler, you might have found a compiler bug.

Comment: No problem, can you please post your license or registration number for VC2015?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes it does compile under GCC 4.9.2 (in C++14 mode.) I forgot to mention it. :">

Comment: @barakmanos: No problem. Could I see your badge?

Comment: @barakmanos: (In case that was a serious question,) If you read the question (the first line, in fact) you'll see that I'm using CTP 6, which requires no special license. The final version of VS2015 is yet to be released.

Comment: Have you tried VS 2015 RC? Microsoft claims to have fixed dozens of bugs. If your bug is still there, MS might be interested to hear about it. Open a bug report, please.

Comment: @usr1234567: I will try the RC in a couple of days (deadlines... deadlines...) but I doubt a bug report like this would do any good, since I can't even reproduce the ICE in a small sample.

Comment: @yzt: Probably MS has the resources to track your problem down. We are volunteers. And it is more likely that you share your code with MS than posting it on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did report this to Microsoft, and after sharing some of my project code with them, it seems that the problem has been tracked down and fixed. They said that the fix will be included in the final VC14 release.

Thanks for the comments and pointers.